# Select a value of selectbox using javascript properly?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-selectbox

I'm trying to select a specific value of selectbox using javascript. I planned to use jQuery to select an element, but somehow the site I'm trying to automate blocked it or not using jQuery.

So, I slected an element using `document.querySelector();`.
Like below.

```js
document.querySelector("#softBoardListLayer > div:nth-of-type(2) > div:nth-of-type(1) > table > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(1) > td > select").selectedIndex = 01;
```

It does work. After running this javascript, Seleectbox shows the value I selected using this command.

but when I hit confirm button at the bottom of the website to go to the next page, website says that I haven't selected anything.

here is the selectbox part of html.

```html
<select data-v-f6ebec28="" name="" id="">
    <option data-v-f6ebec28="" value="">Select...</option>
    <option data-v-f6ebec28="" value="01">Seoul</option>
    <option data-v-f6ebec28="" value="02">Busan</option>
    <option data-v-f6ebec28="" value="03">Jeju</option>
</select>
```

Is there any way to select the value of selectbox properly?

Comment: You need to provide `all` relevant code for us to be able to see what the problem could be. The JavaScript code you have provided is not related to HTML you have added at all.

Answer (score 0):

you have to very small changes in your HTML code.
first, you have to set the id of the select tag.
then, you have to put that id in `document.querySelector("#select-option")` statement.

```js
document.querySelector("#select-option").value = '01';
```

```html
<select data-v-f6ebec28="" name="" id="select-option">
    <option data-v-f6ebec28="" value="">Select...</option>
    <option data-v-f6ebec28="" value="01">Seoul</option>
    <option data-v-f6ebec28="" value="02">Busan</option>
    <option data-v-f6ebec28="" value="03">Jeju</option>
</select>
```

Comment: But the website I'm trying to run javascript code is not mine. So I cannot set the ids.

Comment: can you send me a website URL. I can see more possible ways to implement.

Comment: https://hcs.eduro.go.kr/#/loginHome Click "Go" -> Search School. In that page, I want to select "서울특별시" which means "Seoul" and "고등학교" which means "High School" for the second selectbox. And school name is "구암고" just copy and paste the school name. and after that, you need to hit search button. It'll show a school to select if it's successfully selected and alert if it's not.

Comment: i got it you can try `document.querySelector("select").value = '01';`

Comment: yeah, I tried that but It was not selecting correctly. If I select by just changing the value of selectbox, when I hit search button, It says that I haven't selected anything yet.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `selected` property on the `<option>` element. Not only does this change the UI, it also ensures you get the correct value back from asking the element's `.value` property:

```js
function setSelected(selectEl, valueToSelect) {
  var options = selectEl.children, i = 0;
  for (; i < options.length; i += 1) {
    if (options[i].value === valueToSelect) { // <-- if the option has the value
      options[i].selected = 'selected'; // <-- select it
    } else {
      options[i].selected = null; // <-- otherwise deselect it
    }
  }
}



var select = document.querySelector('select');
setSelected(select, '03');

console.log('Selected value is:', select.value);
```

```html
<select data-v-f6ebec28="" name="" id="">
    <option data-v-f6ebec28="" value="">Select...</option>
    <option data-v-f6ebec28="" value="01">Seoul</option>
    <option data-v-f6ebec28="" value="02">Busan</option>
    <option data-v-f6ebec28="" value="03">Jeju</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I tried but no luck, can you please check my comment on bhumin's answer that I described about the website I'm trying to use these javascripts if you don't mind?